# SetWindowPos fullscreen chrome

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to move any window to any given screen, remaining the window state and the size, making it the foreground window.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public override void MoveToScreen(string screenName) {
    Screen screen = Screen.AllScreens.FirstOrDefault((s) => s.DeviceName.Equals(screenName));

    if (screen == null)
        return;

    List<IntPtr> hwnds = // get hwnds

    foreach (IntPtr hwnd in hwnds) {
        if (!NativeMethods.IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
            continue;

        // if the window has no area continue
        NativeMethods.GetWindowRect(hwnd, out NativeStructs.RECT rect);
        if (this.GetArea(rect) == 0)
            continue;

        string title = NativeMethods.GetWindowTitle(hwnd);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
            continue;

        this.ShowWindow(hwnd, screen);
    }
}

private void ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, Screen screen) {
    // if the window is minimized, restore its actual state the get the correct window-rect
    long style = NativeMethods.GetWindowLong(hwnd, NativeDefinitions.GWL_STYLE);
    bool minimized = (style & NativeDefinitions.WS_MINIMIZE) == NativeDefinitions.WS_MINIMIZE;
    if (minimized)
        NativeMethods.ShowWindow(hwnd, NativeDefinitions.SW_RESTORE);

    // Remove fullscreen mode if set
    style = NativeMethods.GetWindowLong(hwnd, NativeDefinitions.GWL_STYLE);
    bool fullscreen = (style & NativeDefinitions.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW) != NativeDefinitions.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
    if (fullscreen)
        NativeMethods.SetWindowLong(hwnd, NativeDefinitions.GWL_STYLE, style | NativeDefinitions.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);

    // Make window normal if maximized to move it
    style = NativeMethods.GetWindowLong(hwnd, NativeDefinitions.GWL_STYLE);
    bool maximized = (style & NativeDefinitions.WS_MAXIMIZE) == NativeDefinitions.WS_MAXIMIZE;
    if (maximized)
        NativeMethods.ShowWindow(hwnd, NativeDefinitions.SW_RESTORE);

    // set window position. Remain relative screen position.
    this.GetScreenPos(hwnd, out int x, out int y);
    NativeMethods.SetWindowPos(
        hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, screen.Bounds.X + x, screen.Bounds.Y + y, 0, 0,
        NativeDefinitions.SWP_NOZORDER | NativeDefinitions.SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | NativeDefinitions.SWP_NOSIZE | NativeDefinitions.SWP_FRAMECHANGED
    );

    // make window maximized again after move
    if (maximized)
        NativeMethods.ShowWindow(hwnd, NativeDefinitions.SW_MAXIMIZE);

    // Restore fullscreen mode if it was set.
    if (fullscreen)
        NativeMethods.SetWindowLong(hwnd, NativeDefinitions.GWL_STYLE, style & ~NativeDefinitions.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);

    NativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
}
```

The problem is that the window of the chrome browser is not moving when it is in fullscreen mode (F11 or Youtube-Fullscreen) it only changes the window states and remains at the same position. Other browsers (Edge, Firefox, Opera) can be moved but return to the original screen when leaving the fullscreen mode.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can use UI Automation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview with the Transform Pattern (Move method) which is supported by Windows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.transformpattern it's much easier. What's nice is you can experiment many UI Automation behavior with zero line of code if you use the Inspect.exe tool from the Windows SDK (menu "Action")

Comment: Chrome seems to need the handle `WM_SIZE` message, I specified the original width and height for `SetWindowPos`, and commented `SetForegroundWindow`, the window can be moved, but returning to the original screen after exiting the full screen seems to be related to the processing of the window itself.